# SQL | Parent Child relationship in same table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has parent and child key relationship in the same table, I need to find Parent rows that don't have any children(for example row 1 have no other children) and the most recent children (for example like row 17 have 3 children i.e. 10,13,14 and we need to fetch most recent children only which is 10 )
[image]

Comment: For future: please provide examples in copy-able format (not image), best may be example in some online db-engine, like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Also you shold tag your db-engine fe. `sql-server`, `mysql` etc.

Comment: With SQL questions it is important to include an example of the output you are expecting, in this case it is unclear if the result should include the parent and the child in the same row, or if it is acceptable to union the results of the two queries described together into a single result set but as different rows.

Comment: Putting `0` into the `parent_id` column to indicate "no parent" is a bad data model because with that you are no longer able to define a proper foreign key constraint to make sure that you only reference existing parents. You should use `null` instead of `0` so that you can set up the FK constraint

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need one part related to be main parent:

```sql
SELECT parent.*
FROM MyTable AS parent
WHERE parent_id = 0
```

Next you need to find most recent direct child:

```sql
SELECT parent.*, child.*
FROM MyTable AS parent
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS child
  ON child.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent_id = 0
AND RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY child.parent_id ORDER BY child.id DESC) = 1
```

And add no-child ones:

```sql
SELECT parent.*, child.*
FROM MyTable AS parent
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS child
  ON child.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent_id = 0
AND (
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY child.parent_id ORDER BY child.id DESC) = 1
  OR child.id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, but may not be the most efficient way of doing it:

```
select {desired fields}
from your_table
where not exists
(
   select 1 from your_table B
   where B.parent_id = your_table.id
)
UNION
select {desired fields}
from your_table
where id in
(
   select max(id)
   from your_table B
   where B.parent_id = your_table.id
)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want one row per parent.  Either the most recent child or the parent if there are no children.  You can actually do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by coalesce(nullif(parent_id, 0), id
                                order by parent_id desc, id desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```